# The Hamburgermenu of my shopify website (www.skiffaboei.myshopify.com) is not showing after clicking on the icon

Tags: shopify, themes, hamburger-menu

What can I do? I ran into a problem as I tried to use the hamburger-menu not only for mobile but for all devices. I am using the shopify narrative theme. At first everything went fine. After trying to update the code yesterday things changed...

I already removed the code I added yesterday. I don't know what I am missing here.

Can you help? What should i do?
My Website URL: [www.skiffaboei.myshopify.com](http://www.skiffaboei.myshopify.com)

Reviewed the code and removed the changes I made yesterday to the code.

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) (TLDR: no)